# Hash table creation

Tags: c++

A book I'm reading creates a hash table with the following function

```
size_t hash(const std::string &str) {
    int count = 16;
    size_t hash_value = 0;
    const char *cstr = str.c_str();
    while(cstr && *cstr && --count)
        hash_value += (*cstr++ - 'a') << (count % 4);
   return hash_value;
```

What does the `<<` operator do in this context?

Comment: [The answer's on an operator precedence chart.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

Comment: It's the [left bitshift operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Bit_shifts).  `x << y` is `x * (2^y)` where `^` represents power, not XOR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit shift. If you had a number X represented in binary as 00001111, then X << 3 would result in number 01111000. X >> 3 would be 00000001.

Actually, `X << n` is the same as `X * 2^n` (considering overflow of an unsigned type). `X >> n` is equivalent to `X / 2^n`. By `^` I mean power.